# How to set a Sprite to a specific Frame in Godot

Tags: animation, instance, sprite, frame, godot

I have the Player move around and when he enters a new Room (via Instancing) his Sprite shows him facing in the Default direction (in my Case down). So If you enter a Room from any other direction then it looks weird, cause for a short Moment you can see the Player facing down even if you came from the right. How can I tell Godot to set the Player Sprite to a specific Frame in Code, so I can set it to the proper Frame for each Direction. I'm new to Godot and I used HeartBeast Action RPG Tutorial for my Movement. So it's using an AnimationTree and AnimationPlayer. I tried "set_frame" but Godot just says it doesn't know the Method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are following the tutorial series I think you are following ([Godot Action RPG](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9FzW-m48fn2SlrW0KoLT4n5egNdX-W9a))… You are using an `AnimationTree` with [`AnimationNodeBlendSpace2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_animationnodeblendspace2d.html) ([BlendSpace2D](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/animation/animation_tree.html#blendspace2d)).

The BlendSpace2D picks an animation based on an input vector "blend_position". This way you can use BlendSpace2D to pick an animation based on the direction of motion or the direction the player character is looking at. *For example, you can "idle_up", "idle_down", "idle_left", and "idle_right" animations, and use BlendSpace2D to pick one in runtime based on a direction vector.*

Thus, you need to set the `"blend_position"` of the BlendSpace2D like this:

```
animationTree.set("parameters/NameOfTheBlendSpàce2D/blend_position", vector)
```

Where:

- `animationTree` is a variable set to the `AnimationTree`.
- `"NameOfTheBlendSpàce2D"` is the name of the BlendSpace2D you want to set (e.g. `"Idle"`).
- `vector` is a `Vector2D` with the direction you want (e.g. `Vector2.UP`).

*This is shown in the episode 6 of the tutorial series ([Animation in all directions with an AnimationTree](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9aR9IiiHT8&list=PL9FzW-m48fn2SlrW0KoLT4n5egNdX-W9a&index=6)).*

---

You can find a reference project by HeartBeast at [arpg-reference](https://github.com/uheartbeast/arpg-reference), where you can find a function [`update_animation_blend_positions`](https://github.com/uheartbeast/arpg-reference/blob/master/Player.gd#L90) that looks like this:

```
func update_animation_blend_positions():
    animationTree.set("parameters/Idle/blend_position", input_vector)
    animationTree.set("parameters/Run/blend_position", input_vector)
    animationTree.set("parameters/Attack/blend_position", input_vector)
    animationTree.set("parameters/Roll/blend_position", input_vector)
```

Here `"Idle"`, `"Run"`, `"Attack"`, and `"Roll"` are BlendSpace2D, each configured with animations for the corresponding actions, and this function updates them in sync so that they are picking the correct animation.

*As far as I can tell the code from the repository is further refactored from what is show in the tutorial series. This code from the repository is under MIT licence.*